# Why mutating variable directly will rebuild widget?

Tags: dart, flutter

please run this widget:

```
class MyWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyWidgetState createState() => _MyWidgetState();
}

class _MyWidgetState extends State<MyWidget> {
    bool aBoolean = false;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print('aBoolean will change over press button: $aBoolean');
    return RaisedButton(
        onPressed: () {
            aBoolean = !aBoolean;
        },
        child: const Text("Press Me"),
    );
  }
}
```

variable `aBoolean` will change on each press button.. is that mean mutating variable directly will rebuild widget..? so what `setState({})` is for..? should I mutate variable directly or use setState..?

Comment: `"Why mutating variable directly will rebuild widget?"` - no, it will not rebuild your widget: you have to call `setState()` for that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If you just change the state directly without calling setState, the framework might not schedule a build and the user interface for this subtree might not be updated to reflect the new state.

source: [setState method](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/State/setState.html)

It might rebuild without calling setState but as the documentation suggest, it might not work in the next scenario. It's better to mutate state with `setState method`

Answer (score 0):

Widgets do not rebuild unless you call `setState` (with a few exceptions).

As such calling `setState` is not optional.